# Can C++ templates be used to defer the evaluation of their arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a codebase that features a macro that behaves essentially like this:

```
struct to_void {
    template<class T>
    inline void operator&&(T&& t) {}
};

#define cout_if(c) (!(c)) ? ((void)0) : to_void() && std::cout

// --

extern int expensive_op(int c);
void foo(int a, int b) {
    cout_if(a < b) << expensive_op(a + b);
}
```

Is it possible to create a template that retains the syntax of `cout_if` while also preventing the evaluation of `a + b` and `expensive_op` if they are not needed? I can see this sort of thing being useful in other contexts (eg. in embedded DSLs), but the macro seems brittle.

Comment: Operator&& takes two arguments. I'm not sure what the semantics would be or even if it's allowed as a member function. Interesting though.

Comment: C++ doesn't have "lazy parameters" or "call by name" - macro hackery is your only solution (outside of just wrapping the expression in a lambda)

Comment: @doug - the first argument is the instance of `to_void` on the LHS of `&&` operator.

Comment: This macro does not delay the evaluation of `a + b` and `expensive_op` ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/F0nRuX)).

Comment: Templates do not defer anything - if at all, they bring something forward (from runtime to compile time).

Comment: @HenriMenke - yes, it does? Look at the `jge` on line 4?

Comment: @Aconcagua - certainly expression templates can be used to great effect to control when in a program an expression is evaluated (eg. to fuse two loops). It didn't seem _impossible_ in this case, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @AlexReinking You can use expression templates for lazy evaluation of `expensive_op` but then you have to return said template from `expensive_op`.

Comment: @AlexReinking Expression templates depend on specifically designed `operator+` and `expensive_op`, as far as I understand the question, though, it is about *arbitrary* arguments and functions. Doesn't appear comparable to me...

Comment: @AlexReinking  Duh, what was I thinking? Caffeine deprived today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible without changing syntax or modifying `expensive_op`. The basic problem is that, no matter what you do, by the time an overloaded operator is called, the operands have already been evaluated since they must be passed as arguments to the operator function. I don't think there is a way to avoid evaluation of an argument to a function call just by doing something inside the implementation of the function. Therefore, there can't possibly be a way to achieve what you're asking for…

Comment: Guess I need to start lobbying for this in C++2x ;)

Comment: Until then: what you want is not impossible. It's just impossible to make that particular syntax do it (without preprocessor hacks). There would be numerous ways to get the desired behavior if you could modify the syntax. Basically, what you're looking for is inversion of control. As soon as you forward the function and the arguments with which it should be called to `cout_if`, the implementation of `cout_if` can decide whether to make the call or not…

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this without the preprocessor and still maintain the syntax.  A minimally invasive variant would require wrapping the call to `expensive_op` in a lambda.

```
#include <iostream>

extern int expensive_op(int c);

class cout_if {
    bool m_b;
public:
    cout_if(bool b) : m_b{b} {};
    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(T&& rhs) {
        if (m_b) { return std::cout << rhs(); }
        return std::cout;
    }
};

void foo(int a, int b) {
    cout_if(a < b) << [a,b] { return expensive_op(a + b); };
}
```